# Two model Popup in bootstrap webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popup

enter image description here

[image: ![SignIn popup]

[image: SignUp popup]

### I have used two Popup model when I click on signIn button in my website one signIn Popup model will open... If user is not registered it will ask for Create Account ... I have given one href in signin which will open another popup and close first one... The same thing is with second popup window.When user is in second popup there is another href to signIn...

Code For SignIn Popup Model Start

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signIn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="colorStrips">
          <div class="col-sm-3 colorStrips1">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 colorStrips2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 colorStrips3">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 colorStrips4">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-body model-padding">     
        <!-- <div class="col-sm-6"> -->
          <div class="form-group form-area">
            <input type="email" class= "form-control form-field" id="popupSignInEmail" placeholder="Email Address">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-area">
            <input type="password" class= "form-control form-field" id="popupSignInEmail" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="one-block-item form-inline">
          <div class="checkbox col-sm-6">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
          <a href="#forgotPwd">Forgot Pasword ? </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="radial-signin">
          <center>
            <a type="submit" href="#signInData" class="btn btn-signin wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1200ms" data-wow-delay="300ms" data-role="popup-link wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="800ms">SIGN IN</a>
          </center>
        </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
        <div class="toggleTosignUp">
          <center>
            <span class="textofsignin">Are you a new user ? <a onclick="launch_modal('#signUp');" data-toggle="modal" href="#signUp" id="signUpClicked" class="markuptext-S">Create Account</a>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Code for signup popup start

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signUp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="colorStrips">
          <div class="col-sm-3 colorStrips1">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 colorStrips2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 colorStrips3">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 colorStrips4">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="modal-body model-padding">     
        <!-- <div class="col-sm-6"> -->
          <div class="form-group form-area">
            <input type="email" class= "form-control form-field" id="popupSignInEmail" placeholder="Email Address">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-area">
            <input type="password" class= "form-control form-field" id="popupSignInEmail" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="one-block-item form-inline">
          <div class="checkbox col-sm-6">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
          <a href="#forgotPwd">Forgot Pasword ? </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="radial-signin">
          <center>
            <a type="submit" href="#signInData" class="btn btn-signin wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1200ms" data-wow-delay="300ms" data-role="popup-link wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="800ms">SIGN IN</a>
          </center>
        </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
        <div>
          <center class="toggleTosignIn">
            <span class="textofsignin">Already have an account ?<a onclick="launch_modal('#signIn');" href="javascript:void(null);" class="markuptext-S" id="signInClicked">Sign In</a>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I have tried Following JS :

```
function launch_modal(id) {
     $('.modal').modal('hide');
     $('#'+id).modal('show');
     $('body').css({"padding-right" : "0 !important"});
  }

$('#signIn').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
     $('body').addClass('test');
});
$('#signUp').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
     $('body').addClass('test');
});
```

---

Now comes to the problem:
When I go to second model first is closed. But When I want to come at First Model i.e. a signIn Popup from Second popup i.e. a signUp Popup It can't do that..

Comment: and the reason you have pushed the ASK QUESTION button is ?

Comment: so what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the # from the selector:

```
function launch_modal(id) {
     $('.modal').not(id).modal('hide');
     $(id).modal('show');
  }
```

Comment: i.e from the id ... $('#'+id) = $(#signUp)

Comment: @Vaidya the html has `onclick="launch_modal('#signIn')`  which already includes the `#`;)

Comment: or I am trying to make it in one model.... just showing and hiding the model body

Comment: if you don't want to toggle between modals but the body of the modal then use a toggle class that hiddens the body of one of the forms and toggle this between forms